# How can I save form data on a node in Drupal?

Tags: nodes, forms

I want submit form data and save on specific node but I don't know that how to do?

```
function test1_menu() {
  $items['mytest'] = array(
    'title' => 'My Tes',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('test1_form'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'weight'=> 1,
    'type'=> MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );
  return items;
}

function test1_form($form, &$form_submit) {
  $form['firstname'] = array(
    '#title' => t('First Name'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    //'#required' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['lastname'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Client Name'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    //'#required' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#value' => 'Test',
    '#type' => 'submit',
  );
  return $form;
}

function test1_form_form_submit($form_id, &$form_state) {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your submit function, you just need to create a node, e.g.

```
$values = array(
  'type' => $node_type, // Drop in your desired node type.
  'uid' => $user->uid, // Want to set an author?
  'status' => 0,
  'comment' => 0,
  'promote' => 0,
);
$entity = entity_create('node', $values);
```

To make your life easier, I recommend to use entity_metadata_wrapper:

```
$ewrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $entity);
```

Now, you can just cycle through your form data and add the values to the correct fields of your node:

```
$key = '<MACHINE_NAME OF YOUR FIELD>'; // e.g. "field_firstname"
$val = '<VALUE TO BE SET FOR THAT FIELD>'; // e.g. $form_state['values']['firstname']
$ewrapper->$key->set($val);
```

This of course depends on the field type, the above works for example for simple textfields. Finally, if all is set, just save the freshly created node:

```
$ewrapper->save();
```

Comment: And the form values are accessible inside the _form_submit function by using $form_state['values']['firstname']

Comment: Right, I added an example to my answer.